# Asp.net MVC - CMS / Wiki Plugin for Help Center Module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, content-management-system, wiki

I am creating a new website using Asp.Net MVC 5. Our application needs a Help Center Module, which would provide help for different sections of the system to end users.

I am looking for the best suitable option to implement this. The options I am considering at this moment are,

1. Integrate some Asp.Net CMS (preferably free) to allow content management for Help Center Module.
2. Integrate Asp.Net Wiki plugin
3. Create my own admin module to manage content for Help Center module.

I have few more things to factor in mind, in order to make the right choice.

1. I don't want to implement my website with in CMS system. If we go
   for that choice, the CMS system should run side-by-side with the
   application, without affecting any part of the application.
2. The Help Center module should at least have search facility to search among all sections in that module.
3. We will have our own Custom Authentication implemented in our website, and we would want the different sections of help center module should allowed to view / edit / delete by different types of  users in our system using the same custom authentication. i.e. applying existing authentication of website to Help Center module.
4. I would like to have some future proof solution for our system (if possible though not necessary at this moment), as requirement for the website can change in future, and we would love if that can be implemented without much extra effort.

I have seen few similar posts on Stack-overflow for this. However, they are either very old or do not provide enough information, which I want in my case.

Did anybody came across the same situation as of me. I will really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Meghana